# Django cannot access all objects in a model

Tags: python, django, object, model

My view looks like this:

```
class PageView(DetailView):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    template_name = 'page.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['categoryitem'] = CategoryItem.objects.all()
        return context
```

When in template I try to execute the given context variables like so `{{ category }}` it prints out `[<Category: Something not so interesting>]` aka model name + it's title, I presume the title gets printed out because I've set `__unicode__(self): return self.title` in the model.py, but I cannot access any other fields from the given object. `category.id` is blank as so is everything else. How can I access those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is:

```
context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
```

So it should be:

```
context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
```

And in your template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
  {{ category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output you got in your test makes sense:

```
[<Category: Something not so interesting>]
```

it's an array with only one entry, this entry is an object of the class Category, and the string representation of it is "Something not ..."

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the category, since it's queryset. E.g. in your template, you can do

```
<ul>
{% for c in category %}
  <li> {{ c }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`category` in template is queryset ( list of objects) not one single object. You need to iterate over it as

```
{%for c in category %}
    {{c.id}} : {{ c.other_attribute }}
{%endfor%}
```